# Linking function/global variable to specific address with llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

With LLVM, is it possible to specify that a function or global value should be linked to a specific address?

Alternatively is it possible to create linker sections (and specify their addresses) in LLVM IR? (I know that one could then specify a `section` parameter for functions and global variables.

I want to output an object file linked in a specific layout without writing a linker script and running it through `ld.lld` manually. (Either using LLVM IR or the LLVM API.)

Comment: You do that by writing a linker script, making a section whose address is the one you want, and in the IR you [put the function or variable in the relevant section](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html#a959c99adbdc7f8375cf866916c6b60f2).

Comment: @arnt Thanks for the help. I thought there might be a way to avoid the need for a linker script.